# Output on one line all elements of an array that satisfy a condition using BASH

Tags: arrays, bash

The following is to be implemented in a BASH script. I have access to what I think are other "devices" commonly used in bash scripts such as sed, awk, bc, dc etc. I have an array whose elements are strings. The elements are either "none" or a name. This question is in 2 parts. The first goes over the simplest form of the problem with as little background as possible. It is all that is needed I think. The second part is almost entirely background on what I am trying to do in general and may be useful, but I do not think is needed necessarily.

## Part 1: SHORT VERSION

I have an array of strings

An example of this array is

```
array=('none' 'none' 'name1' 'none' 'name2' 'none' 'name3' 'none' 'name4')
```

In my problem the array is much longer. I would like to search if specific elements are 'none' or 'name#' (i.e., not 'none'). AND What I need is to start at element i and check every nth element after that to see if it is 'none' or 'name#' and print all elements that are 'name#' on one line

For this example that means if I want to output starting from say element 2 (array starts at 0) and then checking every 3rd element after that:
    my output for this would be `name1 name4`

if I had started at element 1 then my output would have been `name3`

I do not understand piping sufficiently well to be able to echo with a condition (2 conditions really, the first being the periodic range of elements, the second the name vs none criteria).

## Part 2: LONGER VERSION (NOT NECCESSARY)

I am running a double do loop that calls a program. every once in a while the output is not what I want, so I flag the run name and part of that run that I didn't like. I have this criteria set up it saves the "i" "j" in the name so I know where the failure occurred.

Since bash does arrays and not matrices, I save these failed states in an array that is i * j long. This is why I need to access a certain section. If each run has 3 parts, then in post analysis, for that run, I search the elements that correspond to that loop. i.e. if there are 3 runs with 3 parts in each, then in my array elements 0-2 are run 1, 3-5 are run 2, and 6-8 are run 3. This corresponds to the array I have shown above.

each run has a part 1, 2 and 3 in this example, or in bash syntax a part 0,1 and 2. (i.e. elements 0,3,6 is the first parts of runs 0 1 2 respectively in the above array, 1,4,7 is the second parts of runs 0,1,2 respectively, and elements 2,5,8 are the 3rd parts of runs 0,1,2 respectively). For each set of parts I want to print out all elements corresponding to those parts that are not 'none'

Here is a dummy code snippet of the process (and this works fine, the question pertains to the post analysis part after)

```
k=0
for ((i=0 ; i<$NRuns ; i++)); do
    for ((j=0 ; j<$NPartsPerRun ; j++)); do
        k=$((k + 1))
        #PSEUDO CODE HERE not actual bash
        call program
        if "program output bad" ; then
            array[$k]=$Runname
        else
            echo "Thanks for taking the time to look at my problem"
        fi
    done
done
```

Now for post analysis, I want to know for a given part, which runs failed. i.e for a given "j" what were the runnames of the "i's" that failed

Post analysis (and my issue. The code is a sorry attempt to convey the idea, it is really more of a pseudo code, it is not bash)

```
for ((i=0 ; i<$NPartsPerRun ; i++)); do
    #PSEUDO CODE HERE not actual bash
    #first element to check is $i, then check every Xth element
        if ${array[$i]} || ${array[$(i+X)]} etc.. != 'none' echo "element names that pass condition test"
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: I would seriously consider using a different language, like python for example.

Comment: It is tempting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it solves your problem but I think that it would be something close to this.

```
array=('none' 'none' 'name1' 'none' 'name2' 'none' 'name3' 'none' 'name4')
step=3

echo "array size = ${#array[@]}"
echo "step = $step"

for ((i= 0; i < step; i += 1)); do
    echo -ne  "i = $i: [ "
    for ((j = i; j < ${#array[@]}; j += step)); do
        if [[ "${array[$j]}" != "none" ]]; then
            echo -n "${array[$j]} "
        fi
    done
    echo "]"
done
```

This will output:

```
array size = 9
step = 3
i = 0: [ name3 ]
i = 1: [ name2 ]
i = 2: [ name1 name4 ]
```

This works by using a nested loop to check for the indexes of the form $i + n * $step.

You could, of course, change the way it's printing the values to suit your use case. I hope it answers at least the short version of your question!

Comment: Great answer for the short version.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood the question correctly, you could emulate a matrix with an associative array and make your code much more readable:

```
declare -A matrix=()

# save runs into the matrix
for ((i=0; i<n_runs; i++)); do
    for ((j=0; j<n_parts; j++)); do
        [[ $(program) = bad ]] && matrix[$i,$j]=$name
    done
done

# print unsuccessful runs for a given part
part=2 runs=

for ((i=0; i<n_runs; i++)); do
    [[ ${matrix[$i,$part]} ]] && runs+="${matrix[$i,$part]} "
done

printf '%s\n' "${runs% }"
```

Comment: Excellent answer for the long version.